# How to save Images in their original size using Android Camera API

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I've written some code in a  fragment to open the camera app and once a photo is taken, a photo is saved. I cannot get it to save a full size image, its saving a lower res version. Can anyone spot where I've gone wrong?

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            mNewPhotoPath = getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" +
                    photoFile.getName();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                    "com.example.mmackenz.myholidays.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

This is what I have in my onActivityResult in case that is relevant:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        File newImage = new File(mNewPhotoPath);
        images.add(newImage);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Photo newPhoto = new Photo(newImage.getAbsolutePath(), newImage.getName(), -1, -1);
        DatabaseHandler db = DatabaseHandler.getInstance(getContext());
        db.addPhoto(newImage.getAbsolutePath(), newImage.getName(), -1,-1);
    }

}
```

It adds a new file to an array list which is displayed in a recycler view, and also info of the file in a Photos table.

Thanks

Comment: It's possible that it is a bug in the camera app that you happen to get when using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` in your test environment. Try different devices or camera apps.

Comment: **Photo** is not a standard Android SDK class; neither is **DatabaseHandler**. Please check if **DatabaseHandler.addPhoto()** picks up a thumbnail image.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified these better. Photo is a class I created that holds the file path of the photo and two ID's which are foreign keys from other tables. The database handler's add photo method just adds a new record with the file path populated. It isn't involved in storing the image in anyway, just to keep a record of them because I associate them with other objects in my program through the foreign keys.